# How to compare words of one string in Java with words of another string and separate the words on match?

Tags: java, arrays, string

This was an interview question.
You are told to take string input from user & output a string (or array of string) separated by spaces with meaningful words matching from another string called as Dictionary. You have a dictionary function to check if word exists or not.
For example:
if `Input is "howareyou"
Output should be "how are you"`.
where the words 'how', 'are', 'you' are exist in dictionary string.

*One more example:*
`Input: "somethingneedstobedone
Output: "something needs to be done`
(Assuming that dictionary has words like *something, needs, to, be, done*.

I am not getting when to do k++ if there is no match.

The code I tried:

```
public class Sample1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    int i,j,k,len;
    String[] dict= {"how","are","you","something","needs","to","be","done"};
    //StringBuilder str=new StringBuilder("howareyou");
    StringBuilder str=new StringBuilder("somethingneedstobedone");
    len=str.length();
    for(i=0,j=0,k=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        for(j=i+1;j<len;j++)
        {
            if(dict[k].toString().equals(str.substring(i, j)))
            {
                str.insert(j, " ");
                k++;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(str);
    sc.close();
}
```

The commented case works well, but help me to get second case worked.

Comment: Please include the code you have tried.

Comment: Also, it's not clear how the dictionary is represented.

Comment: `something` could be resolved to `something` and `some thing`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're having (and the reason the first string succeeded and the second does not) is to do with the order of words in the dict.
Your current implementation checks if the words in the dict appear in the string exactly in the order they were entered into the dict - 
after you found the first word, put in a space and proceed to find the second word. If you did not find the next word, you do not proceed with the process.

There are many ways to rewrite the code to get what you want, but the **minimal** change is:

```
public class Sample1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
int i,j,k,len;
    String[] dict= {"how","are","you","something","needs","to","be","done"};
    //StringBuilder str=new StringBuilder("howareyou");
    StringBuilder str=new StringBuilder("somethingneedstobedone");
    len=str.length();
    for(i=0,j=0;i<len;i++) //removed k from here
    {
        for(j=i+1;j<len;j++)
        {
          for (k=0;k<dict.length;k++) { //added this loop!
            if(dict[k].toString().equals(str.substring(i, j)))
            {
                str.insert(j, " ");
            }
          } //Loop closing for k - the dictionary
        }
    }
    System.out.println(str); 
    sc.close();
}
```